# VBA code doesnt add category from defined range in line chart

Tags: excel, vba, graph, categories, linechart

I am  trying to create a line chart through the use of VBA,i do this by using the attached code, I list the category i want in the rng, however it doesn't automatically select this to be the category, i want columns 4,5 to be displayed on the chart and 3 to be the category.

```
Sub CreateGBPChart()
'PURPOSE: Create a chart (chart dimensions are not required)

Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As Object
Dim wks As Worksheet, wks2 As Worksheet

Set wks = Sheet2
Set wks2 = Sheet5

'data range for the chart
lastrow = wks.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  Set rng = Range(wks.Cells(10, 3), wks.Cells(lastrow, 5))


'Create a chart
  Set cht = wks2.ChartObjects.Add( _
    Left:=wks2.Range("K18").Left, _
    Width:=480, _
    Top:=wks2.Range("K18").Top, _
    Height:=200)

' chart data
  cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
  'cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames = Range(wks.Cells(10, 3), wks.Cells(lastrow, 3))

'Determine the chart type
  cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

'chart  title
  cht.Chart.HasTitle = True

'Change  title
  cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "GBP Price"

'Remove Legend
  'cht.Legend.Delete
cht.Chart.Parent.Name = "GBPTable"

'adjust the min val
cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 1
'format fontsize'
cht.Chart.ChartArea.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 8

'cht.Chart.chartSeriesCollection(1).Line.Width = 4
'cht.Chart.chartSeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.Width = 4

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
' cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
  cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=wks.Range(wks.Cells(10, 4), wks.Cells(LastRow, 5))

' Add lines
  cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = wks.Range(wks.Cells(10, 3), wks.Cells(LastRow, 3))
  cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = wks.Range(wks.Cells(10, 3), wks.Cells(LastRow, 3))
```

Comment: Hi Barneyos, Thanks for your reply, it worked perfectly!

Comment: You welcome, and remember you may always rate the answer. ;-)